# How to change IP using Special Administration Console (SAC)?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am accessing a dedicated server using [SerCon](http://faq.1and1.com/dedicated_servers/windows_server/windows_recovery/serial_console_sercon/3.html) as I could not connect to the system now. I, however, managed to get into [SAC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785873%28WS.10%29.aspx)

When I checked the ip using `SAC > i`, it showed me 47.xxx.xxx.xxx where it should ideally be 74.xxx.xxx.xxx
I need to change only the IP and not the subnet (255.255.255.0) and gateway (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

I see the help as

```
i <#> <ip> <subnet> <gateway> set IPV4 addr., subnet and gateway.
```

I tried

```
SAC >i # 74.xxx.xxx.xxx 255.255.255.0 xx.255.255.1
```

I get the error

> Error, missing or invalid network interface number.

Where do I get network interface number?

Update: Microsoft TechNet defines `i`  in *Special Administration Console(SAC)* as,

> If no parameters are passed, this command lists Internet Protocol (IP)
>   information. You can configure IP parameters to display or set the IP
>   address, subnet mask, and gateway of a given network interface device
>   by providing the network number, IP address, and subnet information.
>   To do so, use the following format: `<network#><IPaddress><subnet>`

I need a way to get this command working. I also don't know what should network# contain and where to get that. And doesn't `<>` implies that the field is optional?

I am really out of sorts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cmd` to create a command prompt session, `ch` to connect to it and then `netsh` to configure the network.

Comment: there is a problem with that. i am not able to login with my credentials at all.

Comment: Not even local Administrator credentials?

Comment: asi understand, the problem is that the server ip set and the ip given by hosting porvider are not same and so I need to use `i` for setting the ip using SAC. I have updated what microsoft has to say. what i really need is way to find out the correct parameters to execute i. hope i am clear.

Comment: I don't know what parameter to use in SAC to set the IP address, but starting CMD and using NETSH should do the trick. Of course, if you are unable to login at all, this isn't going to help. Doesn't the "i" command show the interface number, along with its IP settings?

Comment: i have updated my question. btw i reached the sac commandline using a putty. will i get a gui version for this sac anywhere? wishful thinking...

Comment: No, there isn't any GUI version, it's only a command-line shell. Can you paste the output of the "i" command?

Comment: hey, i got that. there was "11," at the start of the output of i command. i gave it after i and got my prob solved. whats # anyway. i mean, what does *i 11 ip mask gateway* mean? specifically whats 11? thanks a lot for your time.